# How to use Perl to count specific characters in a string

Tags: perl, scripting

I have a Perl script that I am using to create a file.

I have a variable that holds a number of file paths separated by commas.

```
path/to/file1,path/to/file2....path/tofileN
```

Depending on how many file paths are returned, I need to create another string that creates random strings, to match with each file up to N files

If my first string variable contains 3 file paths, I need to create a string like

```
RandomName1,RandomName2,RandomName3
```

and write it out to my output file.

- How can I parse the incoming string of file paths to determine how many file paths there are in total?
- How can I write a loop to create a file name for each incoming file path, upto N files?

Comment: for 1, you are probably looking for [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

Comment: I have the feeling that should be asking a more fundamental question. I've answered this for you, but I suggest you take a step back and think about what problem you really want to solve. It might save you a lot of work later.

Comment: Please explain the background to your question so that we can understand what you need to do. Generating a list of random strings is never useful. You have described where the data comes from, but you must explain a lot more about what you are doing with these file paths, and what parts should be random.

Comment: @Borodin that is pretty much what I tried to say in a less specific way, because I thought the question was quite clear, but will cause the OP pains later on because he is probably going about his business in a less than optimal way. On the other hand, we don't know and this could be a really badly formulated homework about working with strings.

Comment: I should've been clearer. I didn't mean to generate a random string. By random name, I meant any sort of string that corresponds to file name. Potentially even name them as File1, File2, File3..FileN. Essentially these names are just labels for a graph to be plotted, and so they are not so critical.

Comment: What kind of program will create these graphs? It seems odd that any program would take a list of paths to directories and a second list of file names to go with each one. That is what started this whole discussion.

Comment: @AspiringGeek: I can't see how random names would help. Perhaps it would be best to use the *real* file name without the path? i.e. (`file1`, `file2`) etc. Or would just `A`, `B`, `C` etc. be better?

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite see why you would put the list of names into a separate string, but here we go.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub create_random_name {
  # return a random filename
}

my $foo = '/home/foo,/root,/dev/null';
my @filenames;

foreach (split ',', $foo) {
  push @filenames, create_random_name();
}

print  join ',', @filenames;

__END__
   efe277fe7aa54f7231dedef7ac8c1e3a,327f56cff4bd21b03ee3ceaa4280014c,7f1ca3feb3b51f7a9ee84f08b1791785
```

Let's see.

- I've created a sub `create_random_name` that should return some randomness. Without further specification of what you need, I will leave that out of the answer.
- We [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) your string of paths into an array, but since you do not want them, we only loop through the results. There is no `my $bar` in the `foreach` for the same reason.
- We only want to create_random_name for the same number of files as there are paths. Those are pushed into `@filenames`,
- which we then [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) on `,` to make them look the same as our starting point, the list in `$foo`.

Comment: Do you really think this is a useful answer? I think you (no one) has established the real requirement

Comment: @Borodin: Can you please elaborate that comment? I'm not sure I understand it. I know what the OP wants sounds strange. That's why I pointed it out in a comment on the question. I also pointed out that what my file name function returns is just random stuff.

Comment: The OP has states pretty clearly what he wants. Create a coma-separated string with a given number of new random file names. The number comes from figuring out how many paths are in the first string that he already knows but does not know how to parse. I think that is clear. I don't know why he would want to do whatever he want to do that way. In fact, I thought the question was quite well-described although it did not have code.

Comment: What I mean is that you have written an entire tested program based on speculation that I'll bet my cat is wrong. You have included `Digest::MD5` which is almost certainly unnecessary and a red herring, and you haven't made any effort at all (in the comments on the question itself, which is where it should go) to determine what the OP's requirements really are.

Comment: Borodin: I concur that `Digest::MD5` might throw him off, but that is why I said one could use whatever one wants and have now removed that from the answer. Fair enough. I also suggested to think about the problem. I did not want to turn this into an IRC-like discussion, where it goes back and forth with 'what do you really want to do?'. The question was well-phrased, though the aim seems not to be useful to us.

Comment: You don't need the dialogue that you fear. Insist that the originator properly specifies his requirement and use your knowledge to help him define it. Use the *most trivial* example as a step to help them define their needs. It needn't be anything remotely workable to help the thought process, but your complete solution involving MD5 is a black hole that discourages them from understanding their own requirement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43550/discussion-between-simbabque-and-borodin)

Answer (score 0):

For 1), you probably want [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) as RC said.  For 2), [File::Temp](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html) should do the trick.

```
use File::Temp 'tempfile';

my $orig_path_str = 'path/to/file1,path/to/file2....path/tofileN';
@orig_paths = split(/,/, $orig_path_str);

my @random_paths;
# loops number of times equalling your number of paths
foreach (1..scalar(@orig_paths)) {   
    my ($fh, $filename) = tempfile();
    push(@random_paths, $filename);
}
my $random_path_str = join(',', @random_paths);
```

Comment: `tempfile` will also create a file on disk, but the OP asked to only create random names. It's not clear if he has writing permissions there. If not, this will fail.

Comment: Ah, yup.  I misread the question to think the random names would be files themselves.  Go with simbabque's answer.

Comment: As my comment on simbabque's answer, isn't this a wild guess as to what the OP may want?

Comment: Tidy this up and `use strict` and `use warnings` and you may almost be right.